# How to calculate number of dice needed to reach total y with probability z

Tags: probability, statistics, dice

I am writing an excel sheet to help with planning for a game I am playing.

In this game, you have units which produce 1d10 points per round.  Each goal is measured against a target.  I am trying to figure out an excel formula to calculate how many units to assign to each goal for a given probability of reaching it that turn.

Each unit provides a roll independent of all other units, and all rolls are evenly distributed between 1 and 10.

In short:

If I want a 50% chance of getting a sum of at least 50 on x fair d10, how do I solve for x?  How does this change if I want a 95% chance of that sum?  How do I put this calculation into an Excel-friendly format?

Comment: Are you only using D10? The scoring is only linear addition? 5 dice produce numbers 5 through 50. One combination produces 5 and one produces 10. The number of combinations for each possible score, though, requires knowing the sample space. That is where the problem gets hard. You can brute force it and save the values for the number of dice you expect to get. Just be aware, if you allow, say, 10 dice, the sample space will have 1E10 possible outcomes ranging from 10 to 100. A quick VB in Excel program can calculate these values for you and sum up the support for each one.

Comment: @PeteMancini: Yes, it is only d10 and the scoring is a straight sum of the dice.  That said, there's currently 90 units to split between the goals, with no 'hard' upper limit (limited in-game by other resources, of course).  So I could conceivably throw 90d10 at a single goal at this point.

Comment: If you only want to do this as a one-time thing and you only have a few cases to handle, it might be quicker to use [Troll](http://topps.diku.dk/torbenm/troll.msp), which is an online (and offline) tool that gives you probability distributions for rolling $x\mathrm{d}y$ for arbitrary $x$ and $y$.  For example, it took me about 2 minutes to find that the answers to your questions are 10 and 12, respectively.

Comment: I think you can use =1-NORM.DIST(50,55,10,TRUE) in Excel. The first number is the number you are seeking to meet or beat. The second number is the number of d10 * 5.5. The next number is the number of d10, and the last value just says take the cumulative probability. Give it a shot. It beats calculating the distribution, by assuming fair dice rolling a normal distribution.

Answer (score 2):

For small numbers of rolls, you can just add them up in Excel.  Let each column be a number of dice and each row be a sum.  The entries will be the number of ways to achieve that sum.  Leave ten blank rows above your chart.  In the column for one die, put a $1$ in each cell from $1$ to $10$ because there is one way to get each number.  In the column for $n$ dice, the cell for sum $s$ should have the sum of all the cells in the column for $n-1$ dice with sums $s-10$ to $s-1$ because the number of ways to get a sum of $s$ is to start with one of those and get the proper number on the last die.  Copy right and down will make this easy.

Now you can make a companion chart for the number of ways to get a sum of at least $s$ on $n$ dice just by adding the applicable cells.  You can make another with the probability to get at least $s$ and just scan for your $50\%$ or $95\%$ chance.

For a large number of dice you can use the normal approximation.  You are adding up a [discrete uniform distribution from $1$ to $10$.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(discrete))  The expected value is $5.5$ times the number of dice.  The variance is $\frac {99}{12}$ times the number of dice.  For a $50\%$ chance of at least $s$ you just need $\frac s{5.5}$ rolls.  For a higher chance you need a result that is some number of standard deviations low to give you at least the sum you want.

Comment: At this point, I have about 90 units to assign to various groups, so it would have to be up to 90 dice (if I threw them all at one).  So the 'small number of rolls' wouldn't fit in this case.  I do not recall from my long-past statistics classes how to use the provided variance to calculate standard deviations, could you elaborate?

Comment: The standard deviation is the square root of the variance.  The variance increases linearly with the number of dice, so the standard deviation goes up as the square root of the number.  You are looking to compute the [Z score](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_score) that corresponds to your desired success probability.  I would guess that the normal approximation is quite good around 10 dice, though worse at probabilities close to $0$ or $1$